# Two normal subgroups and isomorphism theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Question

> Let $N_1$ and $N_2$ be normal subgroups of $G$.
>
> Prove that $N_1N_2/(N_1\cap N_2) \cong (N_1N_2/N_1)\oplus (N_1N_2/N_2)$.

I think the homomorphism must be $\phi : N_1N_2 \to (N_1N_2/N_1)\oplus (N_1N_2/N_2)$

such that $\phi(n_1n_2)=(n_1n_2N_1,n_1n_2N_2)$

Then by 1st isomorphism theorem, $N_1N_2/ker\phi \cong Im\phi$

and $ker\phi = N_1 \cap N_2$

But it is hard to show that $\phi$ is surjective.

What should I do?

Comment: Your subgroups are normal, so your homomorphism is actually $ \phi(n_1 n_2) = (n_2 N_1, n_1 N_2) $. The surjectivity should be obvious now.

Comment: You need to be careful and show that the $n_1n_2$ representation is well-defined.

Comment: Here's another way to think about it: use the second isomorphism theorem on the two factors on the right.

Comment: @SteveD Thanks for noting well-defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you note, it is a simple application of the first isomorphism theorem.

You have correctly defined a morphism
$$
\varphi : N_{1} N_{2} \to \dfrac{N_1 N_2}{N_1} \times \dfrac{N_1 N_2}{N_2}
$$
by
$$
\varphi(g) = (g N_{1}, g N_{2}),
$$
and checked that the kernel is $N_{1} \cap N_{2}$.

As to the image, take an arbitrary element of 
$$
\dfrac{N_1 N_2}{N_1} \times \dfrac{N_1 N_2}{N_2}
$$
and rewrite it 
$$
(n_{1} n_{2} N_{1}, n_{1}' n_{2}' N_{2})
=
(n_{2} N_{1}, n_{1}' N_{2})
=
(n_{1}' n_{2} N_{1}, n_{1}' n_{2} N_{2})
=
\varphi(n_{1}' n_{2}),
$$
where $n_{i}, n_{i}' \in N_{i}$.

Answer (score 1):

You can assume $N_1\cap N_2=\{1\}$, by working in $G/(N_1\cap N_2)$ and using the fact that
$$
N_1N_2/N_1\cong(N_1N_2/(N_1\cap N_2))\big/(N_1/(N_1\cap N_2))
$$
and similary for the quotient modulo $N_2$. It is also not restrictive to assume $G=N_1N_2$.

In this case the isomorphism becomes the usual proof that, for a group $G$ with two normal subgroup $A$ and $B$ such that $AB=G$ and $A\cap B=\{1\}$, we have $G\cong A\times B$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick proof:

The second isomorphism theorem shows

$$ N_1N_2/(N_1)\cong N_2/(N_1\cap N_2) $$

and similarly for the other right-hand group.

So it would be enough to define a map $N_1\oplus N_2\rightarrow N_1N_2/(N_1\cap N_2)$ whose kernel is $N_1\cap N_2$.  That should be easy.

Comment: I use the homomorphism $N_1 \oplus N_2 \to N_1N_2/(N_1\cap N_2) $ by $(n_1,n_2) $ to $  n_1n_2(N_1 \cap N_2)$. But it is hard to show that kernel is $N_1 \cap N_2$

Comment: @pearl: might be easier to consider each map in turn: so first look at the map $N_1\rightarrow N_1N_2/(N_1\cap N_2)$, and think about the kernel there. Do the same then for the $N_2$ side.